# Laravel Stored Dynamic Input field by Model with Boot Function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a Laravel project where I gather some information on Notification Table. But now I have to store 5 more dynamic fields whose input I got from every request on controller. I want to store them by boot model as created by stored. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: why don't you just use a middleware for that

Comment: I have to send notification and store to database after successfully saved all information

Answer (score 0):

You can try with model Observer/model event (creating, created, updating, updated, deleting and deleted).

Comment: it would be great if you could append your answer with code examples of how to implement your suggestions

Comment: It just a classes have method names which reflect the Eloquent events you wish to listen for. for more refer this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers